Solving Hamilton’s equations on curved surface
I wonder if there are analytical or numerical methods that can achieve the light ray tracing on curved surfaces filled with in-homogeneous medium. Specifically, I want to solve the following Hamilton’s equations:
$\dfrac{\text{d} x^i}{\text{d} t} = \dfrac{\partial \omega}{\partial k_i}, \dfrac{\text{d} k_i}{\text{d} t} = - \dfrac{\partial \omega}{\partial x^i}$ ($x^i$ is coordinates, $t$ is time, $\omega$ is frequency and $k$ is wavenumber) on arbitrary curved surfaces, and thus the frequency is metric-dependent: $\omega = \sqrt{g^{ij} k_i k_j}$. The refractive index of the  filled medium can be equivalent to the metric $g^{ij}$.

Did you at least try using your definition for $\omega$ to get more explicit forms for the coupled PDEs?

@CameronWilliams Thanks for your comment. It is exactly what I am trying to do. If this could work, I would report the result as an answer of this question.
